# Is this sequence always eventually periodic regardless of starting value?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, recurrence-relations

$$a(n)=a(\lceil \mathop{\rm abs}(a(n-1)) \rceil\bmod n)) + a(\lceil \mathop{\rm abs}(a(n-2)) \rceil\bmod n))$$
For starting values, $a(0)=a(1)=1$, the sequence has a cycle starting with $n=441329$ having a period of $63584$ (source: https://oeis.org/A330615) For starting value $a(0)=i$ and $a(1)=1$, the cycle starts at $n=35694$ and have a period of $3605$. My conjecture is that for any complex starting values, this sequence eventually cycles. Can anybody prove or disprove this conjecture?

Newer conjecture: The sequence either cycles or eventually forms a arithmetic progression

Comment: Please give some evidence why you believe the conjecture to be true, and  explain why it is of interest.

Comment: @BillDubuque  I just found it interesting that something as simple as a[n] = a[a[n-1]%n] + a[a[n-2] % n] have very intricate sequence. For example, with starting values 1 and 1, this sequence have a very huge cycle that happens relatively late in the sequence

Comment: You gave no supporting *mathematical* evidence. Ditto for the newly added constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starting values $a(0) = 1$ and $a(1) = 2$, the sequence simply satisfies $a(n) = n+1$ and does not eventually cycle; hence the conjecture is false.

Comment: Oh that is one counterexample i completely ignored. My fault